# Get the volume Id of the block device of ec2 instance

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want to get the volume Id of the block device (not the root device) of an instance named "application" :

```
ec2client = session.client('ec2')
response = ec2client.describe_instances(Filters=[{'Name': 'tag-key', 'Values': ['application'] },])
```

How can I retreive the Id from response? I know that the volume id is in the response syntax:

```
'BlockDeviceMappings': [
                        {
                            'DeviceName': 'string',
                            'Ebs': {
                                'VolumeId': 'string',
                                'Status': 'attaching'|'attached'|'detaching'|'detached',
                                'AttachTime': datetime(2015, 1, 1),
                                'DeleteOnTermination': True|False
                            }
                        },
                    ],
```

I tried this:

```
for r in response['Reservations']:
  for i in r['Instances']:
    print i['InstanceId'], i['Hypervisor']
    for b in i['BlockDeviceMappings']:
      print b['Ebs']['VolumeId']
```

But I get nothing .. nothing is printing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just asking how to access the dictionary, this is how:

```
from datetime import datetime
response = {'Reservations': [{'Instances':[{'BlockDeviceMappings': [
                        {
                            'DeviceName': 'Dev1',
                            'Ebs': {
                                'VolumeId': 'Vol1',
                                'Status': 'attaching',
                                'AttachTime': datetime(2015, 1, 1),
                                'DeleteOnTermination': True|False
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            'DeviceName': 'Dev2',
                            'Ebs': {
                                'VolumeId': 'Vol2',
                                'Status': 'attaching',
                                'AttachTime': datetime(2015, 1, 1),
                                'DeleteOnTermination': True|False
                            }
                        },
                    ],
           'other_key': 'other data'}]}]}


out = []
for reservation in response['Reservations']:
    for instance in reservation['Instances']:
        out += [device['Ebs']['VolumeId'] for device in instance['BlockDeviceMappings']]
print out

# outputs ['Vol1', 'Vol2']
```

I've generalized your question a bit to handle the case where more than one device is returned.  If you know you only have one device, you can just use `response['BlockDeviceMappings'][0]['Ebs']['VolumeId']`.

Another way to do this is to use the [AWS CLI](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) and [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/):

```
$ aws ec2 describe-instances | jq -c ".Reservations|.[0]|.Instances|.[0]|.BlockDeviceMappings|.[0]|.Ebs|.VolumeId"`
```

Comment: thank you, when I use `print response['BlockDeviceMappings'][0]['Ebs']['VolumeId']`that gives me `KeyError: 'BlockDeviceMappings'
`

Comment: Can you do `print response`?  I made an assumption that you were showing the whole response dictionary.

Comment: This is what `print response`  gives : 
`{u'Reservations': [], 'ResponseMetadata': {'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'RequestId': '4984584h-1681-403d-850b-db0eb4a99da2', 'HTTPHeaders': {'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'server': 'AmazonEC2', 'content-type': 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8', 'date': 'Fri, 20 Jan 2017 14:14:53 GMT'}}}`

Comment: There you go; there are no Reservations....  that is Reservations in an empty list.